# Preserving status in command function

Tags: c, command

I made a function where you get the output of a command. It works but it doesn't preserve the status of the previous command, for example if you change directory (cd dir) it isn't changed in the new command. Can I change the function such that if I change the directory it is preserved in the next command? This is my function:

```
    int execute(char *command, char *output)
    {
            int rc;
            char buffer[4096], *cmd;
            DWORD byte, bytes;
            HANDLE in_read, in_write, out_read, out_write;
            PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
            STARTUPINFO si;

            cmd = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(command) + 8));
            strcpy(cmd, "cmd /c ");
            strcat(cmd, command);

            ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
            ZeroMemory(&sa, sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES));
            ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));

            sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
            sa.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
            sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

            rc = CreatePipe(&out_read, &out_write, &sa, 0);
            check(rc != 0)
            rc = SetHandleInformation(out_read, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
            check(rc != 0)
            rc = CreatePipe(&in_read, &in_write, &sa, 0);
            check(rc != 0)
            rc = SetHandleInformation(in_write, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);
            check(rc != 0)

            si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
            si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
            si.hStdError = out_write;
            si.hStdOutput = out_write;
            si.hStdInput = in_read;

            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

            rc = CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 
            NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
            check(rc != 0)

            CloseHandle(out_write);

            bytes = 0;
            while (ReadFile(out_read, &buffer, 4096, &byte, NULL)) {
                if (bytes == 0) {
                    bytes = bytes + byte;
                    check(bytes > sizeof(output))
                    strcpy(output, buffer);
                    ZeroMemory(&buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                } else {
                    bytes = bytes + byte;
                    check(bytes > sizeof(output))
                    strcat(output, buffer);
                    ZeroMemory(&buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                }
            };

            CloseHandle(in_read);
            CloseHandle(in_write);
            CloseHandle(out_read);
            free(cmd);

            return 1;

        error:
            free(cmd);

            return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CreateProcess` starts a brand new process that is running independently from yours.

If you make that independent process change its own current working directory, then it will be changed only in the new process, and not in your process running your program.